# How to ignore files without extension in SVN?

Tags: svn

I am tired of manually excluding UNIX binaries from `svn add` commands, how can I tell svn to ignore them?

Answer (score 2):

If these are build artifacts, have your build process put them into their own directory, then `svn:ignore` that directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution I could find:

```
global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so ... \
    # Filenames up to ten lower-case chars wide, without extension,
    # to catch typical UNIX binaries (and most folders!):
    [a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z] \
    [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]
```